# Android pass value to tab

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost

In my Android application I would like to pass a value to a tab... I have a mainActivity then maintabactivity and three tab activities like tab1 tab2 and tab3.. I need to pass three different values to tab1 , tab2 , tab3.. I am able to pass the values... but when I pass values the result is not displaying in inside tab but as seperate pages.. I am giving my code below.. pls help..

MainActivity

```
    //Intent for tab operations

        //Personal Year tab operation
        Intent itab = new Intent(this, TabPersonalYr.class);
        //Personal Year Number
        itab.putExtra("name18",sum18 + "");
        startActivity(itab);

        //Personal Month tab operation
        Intent imonthtab = new Intent(this, TabPersonalMnth.class);
        //Personal Month Number
        imonthtab.putExtra("name19",sum19 + "");
        startActivity(imonthtab);

        //Personal Month tab operation
        Intent idaytab = new Intent(this, TabPersonalDay.class);
        //Personal Day Number
        idaytab.putExtra("name20",sum20 + "");
        startActivity(idaytab);*/
```

MainTabLayout Activity

```
  @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tablay_xm);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();


        // Tab for PersonalYear
        TabSpec photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Personal Year");
        // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
        photospec.setIndicator("Personal Year", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_photos_tab));
        Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, TabPersonalYr.class);
       photospec.setContent(photosIntent);


        // Tab for Personal Month
        TabSpec songspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Personal Month");        
        songspec.setIndicator("Personal Month", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_songs_tab));
        Intent songsIntent = new Intent(this, TabPersonalMnth.class);
        songspec.setContent(songsIntent);

        // Tab for PersonalDay
        TabSpec videospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Personal Day");
        videospec.setIndicator("Personal Day", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_videos_tab));
        Intent videosIntent = new Intent(this, TabPersonalDay.class);
        videospec.setContent(videosIntent);

        // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
        tabHost.addTab(photospec); // Adding photos tab
        tabHost.addTab(songspec); // Adding songs tab
        tabHost.addTab(videospec); // Adding videos tab
```

tab1Activity

```
TextView txt2 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView14);
        txt2.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("name18"));
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you aren't using Fragments per the developer guidelines for tabs?

Comment: No particular reason for that.. I dont know how to use it..

Comment: You should be using Fragments, that's been standard practice for years now. Anyway, be more specific with your problem. What exactly isn't working as expected?

Comment: Actually.. As I mentioned in my question .. I have a MainActivity and three tabs .. and a Tab mainActivity... I need to pass three values to three tabs... when user press on each tab the result has to be displayed in textviews inside the tabs... With the above code I am able to pass the values to the tabs... but it is not displaying like tab.. it is displaying like seperate pages... I think I need to pass the value to the main tab page and then to the tabs.. but I dont have the code for that..

Comment: What do you mean by "not displaying like tabs"? I don't k ow what that means. Can you provide a screenshot or illustration of your problem?

Comment: that means actually ineed display like three tabs in the top and when user press on each tab that tab is highlighted and the result of that page is displayed below... like that.. but instead of that ...no tab is here displayed.. tabs are not displayed... only the page is isplaying

Comment: You appear to have multiple things going on here. I don't see the connection between MainActicity and TabHostActivity. Which one is giving you problems? Depending on that, you problem could be that you're launching 3 Activities from MainActivity. Without further knowledge of what those activities do, however, I can't say for sure.

Comment: I am passing the values to three activities ... so it is diplaying like normal view... not as tab view

Comment: Yes, that is to be expected based on the code you are using. Explain to me MainTabLayoutActivity. Where do you launch that activity?

Comment: which activity... i already given the code above.. actualy I am not an expert in android programming

Comment: You have 2 activities: MainActivity and MainTabLayoutActivity. MainActivity will not show tabs; MainTabLayoutActivity should, if you're doing everything correctly. Where do you start MainTabLayoutActivity? If you never start this activity, you won't see any tabs.

Comment: so what I have to do..I dont know where it will start ...What change I have to do..

Comment: I would look over the Android documentation on Tabs first, you don't seem to have a great understanding of how they work. Here is the appropriate link: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use create singleton Class to pass value

```
public class ShareData{
    private volatile static ShareData shareData;
    public static ShareData data(){
    if(shareData == null){
        synchronized (ShareData.class) {
            if (shareData == null) {
                shareData = new ShareData();
            }
        }
    }
    return shareData;
    }  

    public String value;  
}
```

set value in Tab2

```
ShareData.data().value = "set in tab2";
```

get value in Tab1

```
txt2.setText(ShareData.data().value);
```